# Why this works in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code snippet(working) here, why can  we still use this.review inside `addReview` function. It seems wrong context for using `this.review` because `this` variable must be for `addReview` function not for parent function. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
app.controller('ReviewCtrl',function() {
    this.review= {};
    this.addReview = function(product) {
        product.reviews.push(this.review);
        this.review={};
    }
});
```

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers - personally I would use `$scope` instead at least you are guaranteed on its state at all time.

Comment: @gillesc Thanks for this good post and $scope will do good. But my question is more on fundamentals of javascript, about the scope of `this`. It looks trivial that `this` used in parent function and `this` used in child function should be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not angular, it's javascript and inheritance at play and it all make perfect sense.

If the method was attach to the prototype you would expect `this` to work like it does here. Adding a method in the constructor has the same effect which explains why `this` in the child is the same `this`.

Why wouldn't it? If you think about it why should `this` inside method on the prototype refer to the constructor to, because OOP wouldn't work well without it.

```
function Parent() {

    this.foo = true;

    // this works the same way
    this.childOnContructor = function() {
        console.log(this.foo);
    };

}

// this you expect to work
Parent.prototype.childOnPrototype = function() {
    console.log(this.foo);
}

var parent = new Parent();

parent.childOnContructor();
parent.childOnPrototype();
```